# Access 2013 FE, SharePoint Online List BE. Main form record locks when moving to subforms

Tags: forms, ms-access, sharepoint

I have an Access 2013 FE pointing at Sharepoint Online BE, using linked Sharepoint lists to hold table data.

My main form, which is bound, has several tabs. The first tab contains several fields but the other five tabs contain late-binding subforms. Only the first tab contains bound fields, the other tabs contain sub-form objects.

When a user makes a change in the main form and navigates to one of the subforms in one of the other tabs, it locks the record in the main form. The user can happily move in and out of the subforms and make changes there, but not on the main form anymore. The user is forced to close it and re-open which is a bit of a pain navigation wise. Is there a way to get round this which would allow the user to move back to the main form and continue to make changes, to essentially move around the tabs without the record locking.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and after going through various refreshes the only work around was to press F5 in the form, which will reload the form.

Surprisingly I was not able to achieve the same result with Me.Refresh in VBA as it locks the form the same way.

I ended up just disabling the subforms so they are not clickable and just hyperlinking some fields.

Please share any information you might have discovered since.
Thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible to put some VBA in the main tab click event so that if the main form is dirty it saves then re-opens the form so that for the user there's a short(ish) delay but they can start editing the main form again? If so, what would that code look like??

Comment: I think I have fixed this @pedrobear.
In the tab change event, I said that if the tab selected was the main tab which holds the bound fields, check to see if can open a recordset of that record.
Then do rs.edit.  If the record is locked this throws up error 3218.
In the error trapping, use an IF block so that if error is 3218 then re-open the form, otherwise go through normal error-trapping routine.